# gcc path changes in R studio after updating gcc

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, rstudio

I recently upgraded Linux to 
**GCC 6.4 version(/usr/local/gcc-6.4.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.4.0)
old version 4.6(/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2)**

However, the gcc path has not changed in R studio.
I tried to change using `Sys.setenv(PKG_CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11")`, 
but it is not still working.
what should I do?

```
[linux]$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 6.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

R studio
system2("gcc", "--version")
gcc (GCC) 4.6.2 20111027 (Red Hat 4.6.2-1)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: so when you run `which gcc` and find that they're in different paths; and then `echo $PATH` and find that R studio has a different path, perhaps you should look into the configuration of R studio to fix it's path?

Comment: When you just run `gcc` , /usr/bin/gcc gets run. Which is likely the existing gcc 4.6.2. You need to first figure out where the gcc binary for gcc 6.4.0 resides (perhaps /usr/local/bin/gcc), and place that path before /usr/bin in your PATH.

Comment: echo $PATH indicates ":/usr/local/gcc-6.4.0/". however R studio indicates old version. I have to fix path in R studio. tell me whate to do.